# C# programming stack and defining

Tags: c#, stack

I've found some code on the internet. It's about stack. I put it in a class, but I don't know how to use it from the main class program.

Here is the code:

```
 public class MyStack<T>
{
    private T[] data { get; set; }
    private int SP { get; set; }
    private int Capacity { get; set; }       
    public MyStack(int capacity)
    .......
     ....
     ...etc 
 }
```

I tried this in the main class but it gives me an error:

```
 MyStack item = new MyStack();
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance...

Comment: What error does it give, show your initialization code.  You have to tell it the type of stack you want to initialize.

Comment: `MyStack<int> item = new MyStack<int>(10)` for example. Substitute whatever type you want to use for `int` and whatever capacity you want you stack to have.

Comment: i want an int  stack of capacity =50 ...

Comment: thank you matt burland ,, your code worked for me.. God bless you my friend

Comment: sorry it's just about my english it's not that good,,, that's why many people reported this question as  not understood.. sorry guys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have used the *generics* so when you want to create the instance of such classes then you need to pass the `type` as well like this

```
 MyStack<string> objString = new MyStack<string>(capacity)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your class `MyStack<T>` makes use of [generics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172192%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). When you create an instance, you need to tell it what type of thing you're going to be putting in the stack, for example.

```
var stackOfIntegers = new MyStack<int>(50);
```

This will create a stack that can contain integers (which will presumably get stored in `T[] data`), with a capacity of 50.

Comment: You need to change MyStack stackOfIntegers to MyStack<int> stackOfIntegers

Comment: @TrueEddie - good point! Or just use `var`.

Comment: Yep that works too.  Though I'm not a big fan of var.